# SQL- Subquery with aggregate functions (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server

My set up is as thus: I have three tables-

- Students (StudentID, FirstName, LastName etc.),
- StudentSemesters(StudentID,SemID etc.), and
- Semesters(SemID, Year)

My requirement is to, get the details for each student but only for their last semester. Logically this implies the semester with the highest year number. I cannot seem to get the Query right. For simplicity 'Year' is just an integer (e.g. 2000, 1998). Below is the current query that I have been stuck at for some time:

```
SELECT dbo.Student.LastName + ' , ' + dbo.Student.FirstName AS Student, dbo.Student.Defence1Date, dbo.Student.Defence2Date, COUNT(StudentSemesters_1.SemID) 
           AS SemesterCount, dbo.Student.EntrySemester + ' - ' +
               (SELECT dbo.StudentSemesters.SemID
                FROM   dbo.StudentSemesters INNER JOIN
                               dbo.ListSemesters ON dbo.StudentSemesters.SemID = dbo.ListSemesters.SemID
                WHERE (dbo.Student.StudentCode = dbo.StudentSemesters.StudentCode)
                GROUP BY dbo.StudentSemesters.SemID, dbo.ListSemesters.Year
                HAVING (dbo.ListSemesters.Year = MAX(dbo.ListSemesters.Year))) AS Expr1
FROM  dbo.Student INNER JOIN
           dbo.StudentSemesters AS StudentSemesters_1 ON dbo.Student.StudentCode = StudentSemesters_1.StudentCode
GROUP BY dbo.Student.LastName, dbo.Student.FirstName, dbo.Student.Defence1Date, dbo.Student.Defence2Date, dbo.Student.EntrySemester, 
           dbo.Student.StudentCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the details for only the last semester for each student:

```
SELECT 
  s.LastName + ' , ' + s.FirstName   AS Student,  
  s.Defence1Date, 
  s.EntrySemester + ' - ' + s1.SemId AS Expr1
FROM  dbo.Student               AS s
INNER JOIN dbo.StudentSemesters AS S1 ON s.StudentCode = S1.StudentCode
INNER JOIN dbo.ListSemesters    AS lm ON lm.SemID      = s1.SemId
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT SemId, MAX(Year) AS MaxYear
    FROM dbo.StudentSemesters
    GROUP BY SemId
) AS s2 ON s2.semId = lm.SemId AND ls.Year = s2.MaxYear;
```

**However,** if you're using SQL Server 2005+, you can use the window function to do so:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
      s.LastName + ' , ' + s.FirstName   AS Student,  
      s.Defence1Date, 
      s.EntrySemester + ' - ' + s1.SemId AS Expr1,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s1.SemId
                        ORDER BY Year DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM  dbo.Student               AS s
    INNER JOIN dbo.StudentSemesters AS S1 ON s.StudentCode = S1.StudentCode
    INNER JOIN dbo.ListSemesters    AS lm ON lm.SemID      = s1.SemId
) 
SELECT 
  Student,
  Defence1Date,
  Expr1,
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

But this won't get the `SemesterCount`, but you might be able to make it like this (this is just a guess):

```
SELECT 
  s.LastName + ' , ' + s.FirstName   AS Student,  
  s.Defence1Date, 
  s1.SemCount,
  s.EntrySemester + ' - ' + s1.SemId AS Expr1
FROM  dbo.Student               AS s
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT StudentCode, COUNT(SemId) AS SemCount
   FROM dbo.StudentSemesters 
   GROUP BY StudentCode
) AS S1 ON s.StudentCode = S1.StudentCode
INNER JOIN dbo.ListSemesters    AS lm ON lm.SemID      = s1.SemId
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT SemId, MAX(Year) AS MaxYear
    FROM dbo.StudentSemesters
    GROUP BY SemId
) AS s2 ON s2.semId = lm.SemId AND ls.Year = s2.MaxYear;
```